# Oscar OSGi remote shell service

Tags: java, osgi, oscar-protocol

I'm currently attempting to get my head around OSGi (specifically the [Oscar](http://forge.ow2.org/projects/oscar/) implementation) in attempt to do some funky things with the JVM available on an embedded control system box. To make things a bit easier while I'm experimenting I'm just wondering if:

a) it's possible to have a remote shell service; and
b) if there are any existing implementations to help me get started.

Cheers.

Comment: Why Oscar?? It is obsolete and has been superseded by Apache Felix.

Comment: I would love nothing more than to use current tech but the box's I'm programming are [AMX Integrated Controllers](http://www.amx.com/products/NI-3100.asp). They are a solid hardware platform but are completely closed system that support a propriety scripting language alongside a JVM. In it's vanilla state however the only way to utilize it is via a variation on Oscar bundles which are installed and started via the scripting language. What I'm hoping to do is have the ability to autostart bundles via the system.properties and do away with the scripting language and bloated communications API.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Oscar is still actively developed.

[Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/) provides the [Felix Remote Shell](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-remote-shell.html) service.